# Solve this sql puzzle

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem to solve this [case](http://beyondrelational.com/puzzles/challenges/106/calculate-the-payroll-hours-of-employees.aspx) for my improvement in SQL:

What I have come far is located below but still isn't comppleted.

```
SELECT 
    a.EmpID, 
    a.EarningCode, 
    c.WeekStart, 
    c.WeekEnd, 
    CAST(  (substring(a.EndTime, 1, 2) + '.' + substring(a.EndTime, 4, 2)) AS decimal(4,2)  ),
    CAST(  (substring(a.StartTime, 1, 2) + '.' + substring(a.StartTime, 4, 2)) AS decimal(4,2)  ),
    a.EndTime,
    a.StartTime
FROM TC72_EmployeeVisits a, TC72_Employees b, TC72_PayrollWeek c
WHERE a.EmpID = b.EmpID and c.EmpID = a.EmpID and c.EmpID = b.EmpID
```

Comment: Tell us 1) what you are trying to do, AND 2) since this is for a public challenge contest, how much you want us to help you.

Comment: 1. Distinguish between empID and Hours
2. In this case, just some keywords.

Comment: @FullmetalBoy - any thoughts or comments on my solution??  Does it work for your contest?

Comment: Wow... not bad, not bad at all! Thanks for ya help and my knowlege in SQL has now been increased. How long did it take to complete?

Comment: I have another question for you:
I have a quesion to you.
It's about the syntax code "cte1 c2 ON c1.seq = c2.seq - 1".

When you don't use the "-1", you won't show the employer name, ID, Week with support of syntax code.

The thing I don't understand is that if you have "-1" in what structural process does it attempt to display Irina WIlliams?

Comment: The second part of the union compares record 2 with record 1, then record 3 with record 2, etc. It returns fields when  for e.g. record 3 does not match record 2. The first part of the union simply returns the first record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.  It was fun.  Thanks for the challenge.

```
;WITH cte0 AS
  (SELECT 'H' AS RecType,
          e.EmpID,
          e.EmpName,
          w.WeekStart,
          w.WeekEnd,
          NULL AS EarningCode,
          NULL AS Hours
   FROM dbo.TC72_EmployeeVisits v
   JOIN dbo.TC72_PayrollWeek w ON v.VisitDate BETWEEN w.WeekStart AND w.WeekEnd
   JOIN dbo.TC72_Employees e ON v.EmpID = e.EmpID
   GROUP BY e.EmpID,
            e.EmpName,
            w.WeekStart,
            w.WeekEnd

   UNION 

   SELECT 'D' AS RecType,
          e.EmpID,
          e.EmpName,
          w.WeekStart,
          w.WeekEnd,
          v.EarningCode,
          cast(SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(datetime, v.StartTime), CONVERT(datetime, v.EndTime))) AS float)/60 AS Hours
   FROM dbo.TC72_EmployeeVisits v
   JOIN dbo.TC72_PayrollWeek w ON v.VisitDate BETWEEN w.WeekStart AND w.WeekEnd
   JOIN dbo.TC72_Employees e ON v.EmpID = e.EmpID
   GROUP BY e.EmpID,
            e.EmpName,
            w.WeekStart,
            w.WeekEnd,
            v.EarningCode),
 cte1 AS
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY EmpId ASC, RecType DESC) AS seq, *
   FROM cte0),

 cte2 AS
  (SELECT c1.seq,
          c1.EmpId,
          c1.EmpName,
          c1.WeekStart,
          c1.WeekEnd,
          c1.EarningCode,
          c1.Hours
   FROM cte1 c1
   WHERE seq = 1

   UNION 

   SELECT c2.seq,
          EmpId = CASE WHEN c1.EmpId = c2.EmpId THEN NULL ELSE c2.EmpId END,
          EmpName = CASE WHEN c1.EmpName = c2.EmpName THEN '' ELSE c2.EmpName END,
          WeekStart = CASE WHEN c1.WeekStart = c2.WeekStart THEN NULL ELSE c2.WeekStart END,
          WeekEnd = CASE WHEN c1.WeekEnd = c2.WeekEnd THEN NULL ELSE c2.WeekEnd END,
          c2.EarningCode,
          c2.Hours
   FROM cte1 c1
   JOIN cte1 c2 ON c1.seq = c2.seq - 1
   WHERE c2.seq > 1)

SELECT EmpId,
       EmpName,
       WeekStart,
       WeekEnd,
       EarningCode,
       Hours
FROM cte2
ORDER BY seq
```